# How to get with javascript how many inches/centimeters moved the phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am developing a website which need to get how much centimeters moved the phone and in which direction. I found the accelerometer and the gyroscope, but with the first one I only can see if the phone moves, and with the second one I can see which direction, that's ok, but I don't know how to get how much moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very nature of the accelerometer means it will not be easy to calculate the distance moved. Basically you would need to write a differential equation that calculated the (3D) velocity of the phone after some kind of acceleration took place, and integrated that into a distance moved. The accuracy of the calculation would be very low without some kind of reference point and calibration of the accelerometer.

You would be better off querying the GPS to work out your new coordinates, but that's probably not that accurate either.

Comment: Thanks but the GPS is too large for me, I need just few centimeters, or max few meters. As I know the GPS is not that accurate, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, the GPS isn't that accurate. Another option might be to use a bluetooth or wifi signal. Why do you need to measure the distance?

Comment: I have to "scan" the size of furniture for example, or the size of the room if is it larger, but maybe that's the largest, how can I get the distance between things with wifi, or bluetooth?

Comment: I don't know how you would go about it, all I know is that the signals are directional, and the signal strength varies with distance, so in theory it could be used to calculate position, although there are many complications like echoes from walls which give fake signals. What about a measuring device like surveyors use to measure room dimensions? https://sydneytools.com.au/bosch-glm-50-pro-laser-rangefinder-50m-measure-distance?fee=4&fep=5499&gclid=Cj0KEQiA2uDEBRDxurOO77Cp-7kBEiQAOUgKV2117g1JGq9SzmUGs2JQ0KhHJFbgakSySUIRTk5jbC8aAgcK8P8HAQ